# Why do Muslims say Subhan Allah, Alhamdulillah and Allahu Akbar for 33 times after daily prayers?

Tags: salat, islamic-basis, muslim-practices, dhikr

Muslims say Subhan Allah, Alhamdulillah and Allahu Akbar for 33 times after each daily prayer (salat). What do these words mean and what is the reason for saying them?

Also, why exactly 33 times ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions,

**Subhan Allah** (**سبحان الله**) means "*Allah is free from imperfection*".

**Al-hamdu lillah** (**الحمد لله**) means "*All praise is due to Allah*".

**Allahu Akbar** (**الله أكبر** ) means "*Allah is Greatest*".

Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him has said that these are some of the dearest phrases of Allah Swt and and has lot of benefits in reciting these,

> Ka'b bin 'Ujrah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The
>   Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "There are some words, the reciters of
>   which will never be disappointed. These are: Tasbih [saying
>   'Subhan-Allah' (Allah is free from imperfection)], thirty-three times,
>   Tahmid [saying 'Al-hamdu lillah' (praise be to Allah)] thirty-three
>   times and Takbir [saying 'Allahu Akbar' (Allah is Greatest)]
>   thirty-four times; and these should be recited after the conclusion of
>   every prescribed prayer."
>
> [Muslim]

And

> It was narrated from Nu'man bin Bashir that : the Messenger of Allah
>   (ﷺ) said: "What you mention of glory of Allah, of Tabsih
>   (Subhan-Allah), Tahlil (Allahu-Akbar) and Tahmid (Al-Hamdu lillah),
>   revolves around the Throne, buzzing like bees, reminding of the one
>   who said it. Wouldn't any one of you like to have, or continue to
>   have, something that reminds of him (in the presence of Allah)?'"(Ibn
>   Majah)

And Also know as Tasbih Fatima

> Narrated Ali bin Abi Talib Fatima came to the Prophet (ﷺ) asking for a
>   servant. He said, "May I inform you of something better than that?
>   When you go to bed, recite "Subhan Allah' thirty three times, 'Al
>   hamduli l-lah' thirty three times, and 'Allahu Akbar' thirty four
>   times. `Ali added, 'I have never failed to recite it ever since."
>   Somebody asked, "Even on the night of the battle of Siffin?" He said,
>   "Even on the night of the battle of Siffin."(Bukhari)

And

> Narrated Abu Huraira: Some poor people came to the Prophet (ﷺ) and
>   said, "The wealthy people will get higher grades and will have
>   permanent enjoyment and they pray like us and fast as we do. They have
>   more money by which they perform the Hajj, and `Umra; fight and
>   struggle in Allah's Cause and give in charity." The Prophet said,
>   "Shall I not tell you a thing upon which if you acted you would catch
>   up with those who have surpassed you? Nobody would overtake you and
>   you would be better than the people amongst whom you live except those
>   who would do the same. Say "Subhana l-lah", "Al hamdu li l-lah" and
>   "Allahu Akbar" thirty three times each after every (compulsory)
>   prayer." We differed and some of us said that we should say,
>   "Subhan-al-lah" thirty three times and "Al hamdu li l-lah" thirty
>   three times and "Allahu Akbar" thirty four times. I went to the
>   Prophet (ﷺ) who said, "Say, "Subhan-al-lah" and "Al hamdu li l-lah"
>   and "Allahu Akbar" all together [??], thirty three times."(Bukhari)

And offcourse there would be some wisdom in the number 33 known to Allah Swt and His Messenger and in some narrations we see Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him has given this tasbih to recite 10 times as well,

> Anas bin Malik narrated that : Umm Sulaim came upon the Prophet and
>   said: "Teach me some words that I can say in my Salat." So he said:
>   "Mention Allah's Greatness (saying: Allahu Akbar) ten times, mention
>   Allah's Glory (saying: Subhan Allah) ten times, and mention Allah's
>   praise (saying: Al-Hamdulilah) ten times. Then ask as you like, (for
>   which) He says: 'Yes. Yes.'"(Tirmidhi)

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: Does SubhanAllah mean Glory Be to Allah?