# Why don't we say Mashallah 33 times?

Tags: arabic, terminology

It's quite normal to say [Subhan Allah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subhan_Allah), [Alhamdulillah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alhamdulillah) and [Allahu Akbar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takbir) 33 times after daily prayers; see e.g. [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32596/17163).  I'm wondering why we don't likewise say [Mashallah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashallah) ("God has willed") 33 times.

**Question**: Why don't we say Mashallah 33 times?

This may be because it's unsuitable or clunky to say, which may be more obvious to an Arabic speaker.  [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=Why+don%27t+we+say+Mashallah+33+times?) doesn't seem to help answer the question.

Comment: Basically we don't have any evidence for saying this except the verse in surat al-Kahf verse 39. So some scholars seem to approve saying so it is said that Imam Malik had put a calligraphy on the door if his house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shia view is the following:
The dhikr being recited after every salat - **34**x *Allahu Akbar*, 33x *Alhamdulillah*, *33x Subhanallah* and 1x La illaha illallah- was taught by the Prophet to his daughter Fatimah and is known as [Tasbeeh of Fatimah](http://en.wikishia.net/view/Tasbih_of_Lady_Fatima_(a)).

As everything the Prophet said and taught to people was inspired by Allah swt, it can be concluded that this tasbeeh is a divine recommendation to [benefit](https://www.duas.org/tasbihzehra.htm) its reciter.

> It has immense significance in the eyes of the infallible Imams (a.s.) and the Shiite jurists. It is a simple ,short yet very powerful act of worship from the aspect of performance;  its effect, reward and merit are abundant.

```
https://www.duas.org/tasbihzehra.htm
```

To gain the described rewards and merits, we must not alter the tasbeeh but stick to its exact form. For this reason, we do not add Mashallah to it.